# jms topic Connenction factory lookup hangs

Tags: jms, hornetq, jms-topic

I am trying to connect to HornetQ and perform  look up on topic connection factory b`TopicConnectionFactory hornetQConnectionFactory = (javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");` but it gives an error "javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory]".Please help

```
       Properties p = new java.util.Properties();

      p.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
      "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");

      p.put(javax.naming.Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
      "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");     


      p.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://172.26.178.137:3900");

      // Step 1. Create an initial context to perform the JNDI lookup.
      System.out.println("Step 0.5");
      ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext(p);        
      System.out.println("Step 1");   


     // Step 3. Perform a lookup on the Connection Factory

      TopicConnectionFactory hornetQConnectionFactory = (javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");

     System.out.println("Step 1.5");

     String hornetQTopicName = "topic/Test";

      Topic hornetQTopic= (javax.jms.Topic)ic.lookup(hornetQTopicName);
```

Comment: HornetQ config<entries>
         <entry name="/ConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>
   <topic name="UPM-ETHAN">
      <entry name="topic/UPM-ETHAN"/>
   </topic>

Comment: Hornetq config <connectors>
     <connector name="netty">
       <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
       <param key="host"  value="localhost"/>
       <param key="port"  value="5445"/>
     </connector>